# How can you make variable references different from others?

Tags: javascript

I am making a Pokemon game in which each Pokemon is an object, and each player, player and opponent randomly get a different Pokemon

```
var pokeArray = [fryno, snark, tucoret];
var playerPoke = rand(pokeArray);
var oppoPoke = rand(pokeArray);
```

`rand` is a function I made to randomly pick something from an array
anyway, the problem is that, when the two happen to be the same, I run into problems,
lets say both end up being `fryno`

```
playerPoke = fryno;
oppoPoke = fryno;
```

Then, when I do damage to `oppoPoke`, it is actually doing damage to `fryno`, and thus the `playerPoke` also gets damage, because it is `fryno` too

So I was wondering if it is possible that even if `playerPoke` and `oppoPoke` are `fryno` if they can reference different copies of `fryno` and not `fryno` itself
so that I do damage to `oppoPoke` and not `fryno`
if any of that makes sense

Comment: You'll have to write code to make copies of your base objects. Exactly how that will have to work depends on the nature of the objects.

Comment: I suggest you take this to a new level and use instantiated objects to avoid targeting multiple pokemon with the same attack

Comment: Make the pokemon a constructor and create instances of it: `function Fryno() { ... }; playerPoke = new Fryno();`

Answer (score 1):

You should create a clone of the object. Or better still, instanciate something.

```
function Pokemon(species) {
    // look up species data
    this.hp = speciesData[species].hp;
    this.atk = speciesData[species].atk;
    // and so on
}
```

Then:

```
var playerPoke = new Pokemon(rand(pokeArray));
```

In this case, `pokeArray` should be an array of species names, not an array of objects.

Comment: Well, presumably the data has to come from somewhere, right? Like the `fryno`, `snark` and `tucoret` objects in the original question.